# Accessing Django Form Error Message in View

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

In my view I can access `form['item'].errors` and it gives me something like:

```
> form.is_valid()
 False
> 
> e = form['name'].errors
>
> print e
 <ul class="errorlist"><li>There already exists an item with this name. Try a different one.</li></ul>
>
> e.as_text()
* name\n  * There already exists an item with this name. Try a different one.
```

However, how do I access the `There already exists...` error message without either the HTML tags or the `*name\n *` showing up?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the issue. There is an error message which you can access by doing "form['item'].errors". You want to access this error message with an <li> tag?

Comment: Okay makes sense now. In the Django template, when you do `{{ form.FieldName.errors.as_text }}` does it still show the `* name\m *` part? Also, when you do `form.FieldName.errors.as_text()` does it also still show the `* name\m *` part?

Comment: @user2719875 When I do `form.name.errors.as_text()`, I get AttributeError: 'CreateItemForm' object has no attribute 'name'. Did you mean `form['name']` ?

Comment: do `form.item.errors.as_text()`

Comment: @user2719875 same thing

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I believe you are looking for `as_data()`.

For the whole form:

```
print(form.errors.as_data())

{'foo': [ValidationError([u'This is an error.'])], 'bar': [ValidationError([u'This is another error.'])]}
```

For just a field:

```
for e in form.errors['foo'].as_data():
    print e

[u'This field is required.']
```

Answer (score 0):

in your view.py file

```
error = form.errors
a =list(error.as_data()["error_filed_name"][0])
print(a[0])
```